# UIPickerView returning previous selection as animation isn't complete

Tags: ios, animation, uipickerview

This seems to be a common occurrence, but I am unable to work out how to resolve it.  I have a 'Enter' button to utilise a selected row from a picker view; however, if the animation is not yet finished the previous value is used (event though it looks like it should be picking the closest value).

My solution is to disable the 'Enter' button while the animations are taking place.

However, it would seem that the animationKeys no longer works and I am unable to work out the starting and stopping animation delegate methods of the picker view as they are called as class methods and, for the life of me, I cannot fathom how that can link to a particular view.

Can anyone shed any light on how I can determine if the picker view is being animated or how the class methods are implemented to relate to a particular object?

Comment: Still been trying to work through this; the pickerView:titleforRow:forComponent and pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView only fire if the scroll wheel add or removes rows from the display; so if number of rows is less than the number the wheel can display, they never fire.

Comment: If there was a way of determining if the picker wheel has moved, the button could be disabled - this would allow the 'Enter' button to be enabled when the didSelectRow fires.

Comment: So, the upshot is, is there a way to determine when the picker view animation starts?